# SharePoint Server 2019 Website Mobile View asking for the login authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

Issue in site UAT
Link - https://login.amaf.ae/SitePages/Home.aspx

How we can solve this promt authentication in mobile view in sharepoint server 2019 website. In destop view is working properly for the anonymous users only with the mobile we having issue.

I have tried the following,

- Enabling anonymous authentication in IIS.
- In Central Admin enabled the anonymous authentication
- In permission group also added the anonymous group for the entire website

Thanks for Advance in solving this matter.